# Minecraft Title Screen Zoom Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m setting up Minecraft for my little brother on the family HP laptop(Windows) and the client is so zoomed in. All I can see from the start page is “necra” from the Minecraft logo and the only thing I can select is singleplayer. I’ve looked at all these solutions online and changing DPI settings in properties or the launcher client installations/resolution doesn’t fix the problem, and I cannot select options as single player is the only thing there. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does pressing F11 do anything helpful?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What's the resolution of your display? That, as well as the specs of your laptop would help us diagnose your issue.